# how to remove InnerHTML verbosity in Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I've created the code like below:

```
<div [innerHtml]="post.content"></div>
```

Angular Universal renders the code like below:

```
<div innerHTML="<strong>Hello World</strong>"><strong>Hello World</strong></div>
```

The result is totally acceptable if the text is short enough, however, it will generate double amount of the content. If the text is huge, the result is very verbose.

Is there any option to remove this section or omit the property only for the universal rendering?